# sql query subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query where it takes my total sales and subtracts by my canceled sales, however if there are no canceled sales the value is null. then when the

so basically if my canceledsales where null it returns a null value for the subtraction column instead of the totalsales

```
totalsales-canceledsales(null) = null
1000-null=null
```

i want it to be like this

```
1000-null=1000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper ANSI SQL way would be (taking into account `totalsales` and `canceledsales` could both be null):

```
coalesce(totalsales, 0) - coalesce(canceledsales, 0)
```

You may also see the use of ISNULL on SQL Server:

```
isnull(totalsales, 0) - isnull(canceledsales, 0)
```

Comment: so my actual expression in the query builder is SUM(APRICE) - isnull(SUM(CancelRevenue) ,0)

Comment: No, it would be sum(aprice) - sum(isnull(cancelrevenue, 0))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that any function against NULL is NULL. In this case, NULL means unknown.

If you subtract a number from an unknown number, the result is unknown.

If you subtract an unknown number from a known number, the result is unknown.

Both numbers must be known in order to return a known answer. In this case if one of the operands is NULL, NULL is the correct answer.

However, if you'd rather see 0 than NULL, then use ISNULL():

```
totalsales - isnull(canceledsales, 0)
```

The book [SQL AntiPatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) has a whole chapter better explaining NULL.